# Understanding Wordpress database meta_id and post_id multiple entries

Tags: wordpress

I am a rookie trying to learn how to understand and edit database entries in phPMYadmin. I apologise in advance for the basic question.

When I look at the wp_postmeta table in a wordpress site, there are many dozens of 'meta_id' and 'post_id' entries for the exact same page content. When I edit the page content, a new row is again created, and some of the past rows will contain the new edits, and others will not. I am trying to make sense of it, so that I can also clean it up and delete old entries. I just can't work out which ones should stay and which should go.

If anyone can shed light on this in simple terms, I would be most grateful.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in WordPress you have a thing called "Revisions". Those are basically older versions of your same post/page that are kept in your database if you want to roll-back.

Now the post_id that you mention there, will always be the same independently of the number of revisions. That is the ID associated to your post/page and it will never change.

Regarding your meta_id, that's the logic of WP to work with a thing called "custom fields".

You know, the way metas work can actually be a problem if you want to create a big website like, for instance, an online shop with 100k products and 30 metas for each product. This, only in metas for products, will result in 3M entries in yout postmeta table inside your database - not pretty!

So usually when we want to create a big website, the best way is to manually create some independent tables and work with that.

Now, for the majority of the websites online, the way WP works it's enough, as far as it is properly coded so it won't be doing multiple queries that end up using a lot CPU to process all queries.

So, meta_id if, as it happens with your post_id, the UID for your custom fields.

I hope helped you with this, but if not a quick Google search based on this explanation will clear things out for you. :)

Comment: Thanks. The post revisions relationship makes sense. In my case the meta_id and post_id are all different for each row. So how do you tell which is the current latest 'live' row? Is it just the one at the very top of the list or the one with the highest meta/post number?